# Sybase get today result, two way comparison

Tags: sybase, getdate

I don't know how to test the performance of these two way of getting what i want.

```
select * 
from table 
where column like '%'+left(getdate(),11)+"%

select * 
from table 
where
              DATEPART (DD, column) = DATEPART (DD, GETDATE())  
      AND     DATEPART (MM, column) = DATEPART (MM, GETDATE())  
      AND     DATEPART (YY, column) = DATEPART (YY, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Stopwatch? Indexes? More details?

Comment: The second code with the datepart function is everywhere in the system I've to maintain. I just curious if I introduce the first code whether it will be an improvement. Just want to know if someone else hove done the same.

Comment: I am looking for an answer like... "like use more resource, or the datepart combination use more resource" and some references.

Comment: There are so many variables to consider. What's the data, what's the caching strategies in in place, disk access and paging etc. Try it with 5 million rows in the same table and see what you get. Then you can start to analyse if you want to know better. Otherwise without the data it's micro-optimisation and good intention. If you do go further I found the book Inside Sql Server invaluable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in SQL you can just loop through executing the statement however many times and calculating the time to execute for each statement. Do this a few times to be sure and compare the results.

```
declare @startTime datetime
declare @endTime datetime
declare @execution BIGINT

SET @execution = 0

set @startTime = GETDATE()
while (@execution < 1000000)
begin    
    --TestSyntax goes here


    SET @execution = @execution + 1

end
set @endTime = GETDATE()

SELECT DATEDIFF(ms, @endTime, @startTime) AS 'TimeToExecute'
```

Also know, string comparisons are typically slower in all languages.

Comment: tq! tq! I will wait for a couple of hour to see if some else have another suggestion.